# Insert a character after every n characters but only for the first x occurrences

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string of 13 characters say XXXXXXXXXXXXX. I wish to enter a hyphen after every three characters but only for the *first three* occurrences using JQuery and possibly Regular Expressions.

Which means I need my string to be XXX-XXX-XXX-XXXX.

If I use `str.replace(/(.{3})/g, "$1-")`, `str` being my string, as I came across in another post, it yields me `XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX-X`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks guys.

Comment: Why searching for a hard way? Use loop.

Comment: Thanks for that David but I thought a RegEx will make my life easier :)

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: Hi icedwater, I found a RegEx in another post that is something like str.replace(/(.{3})/, "$1-"). But that will yield a string like XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX-X

Comment: @Kumar You should always include that originally, so we know you've attempted something and aren't just telling us to solve it for you

Comment: @Kumar No need to apologize to me - you just could've avoided whoever's downvotes and gotten (better) answers sooner

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What about `.replace(/(.{3})(.{3})(.{3})/,'$1-$2-$3-')`?

Comment: jcsanyi, could you just help me understand your suggestion?

Comment: Also - shouldn't there be a `^` at the beginning?

Comment: I wouldn't agree that it's clearer, but that's just a matter of preference/habit I suppose. It's a valuable comment to the answer, regardless.

Comment: @jcsanyi Shorter by 1 character? And it's definitely not "clearer". The `{#}` is there for a reason

Comment: @Kumar I'd suggest this: `.replace(/^(...)(...)(...)/, '$1-$2-$3-')`

Comment: I don't see a scenario where it'd be a problem that there isn't a `^` in this particular expression?

Comment: By cleaner, I meant easier to understand at a glance - especially since it's only three. You're right, the `^` is not required because of the way the expression is evaluated left-to-right - but I like the way it makes it obvious instead of depending on the implementation which may not be as well known. Both items are just personal preference though.

Comment: @jcsanyi And since `.` matches any character, the `^` is unnecessary as `.` will always match the beginning of the string

Comment: Hi David, I found your original answer helpful. So unless there is a scenario where it's likely to fail, I am going to use it :)

Comment: @Kumar David's answer will work perfectly. I was just offering equivalent variations, not fixing any problem with it.

Comment: Your suggestions are welcome jcsanyi. You guys are awesome :) thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it with Regex this could work...

```
 // Not nice but works
 var text = "XXXXXXXXXXXXX";
 text.replace(/(...)(...)(...)(....)/g, "$1-$2-$3-$4");
 // Result  "XXX-XXX-XXX-XXXX" Chrome 27+
```

Comment: Yes i saw it after the submit, thats why i voted that answer up.

Comment: hey winner_joiner, for 1112223334444, your solution gave me $0-111-222-333 :(

Comment: Ups sorry, the $-parameter start with 1 not 0. In trying to be fast, i copied the wrong line, and wasnt still even the first. i corrected the  mistake :) Thanks for the catch